# Django - How to make a current object "ImageField attribute" as the pre-defined value in a Update_Object view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-orm

I'm creating an update view using django-form for updating one of my objects that have the following fields:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='object_logo/')
    text_1 = models.TextField()
    text_2 = models.TextField()
```

So, i have created the following form in forms.py:

```
class ObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = [
            'name',
            'logo',
            'text_1',
            'text_2',
        ]
        labels = {
            'name': 'Name',
            'logo': 'Logo',
            'text_1': 'Text 1',
            'text_2': 'Text 2',
        }
```

and defined the following view called `update_object`:

```
def update_object(request, value):
    object = get_object_or_404(Object, pk=value)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ObjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            object.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            object.logo = form.cleaned_data['logo']
            object.text_1 = form.cleaned_data['text_1']
            object.text_2 = form.cleaned_data['text_2']
            object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myApp:detail_object', args=(value, )))
    else:
        form = ObjectForm(
            initial={
                'name': object.name,
                'logo': object.logo,
                'text_1': object.text_1,
                'text_2': object.text_2,
            }
        )
    context = {'object': object, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'myApp/update_object.html', context)
```

My problem is: even with an "initial" value stetted up for `logo`, i have to select an image every time i will update my object (otherwise i receive the `update_object` page with the message "This field is required").

Is there a way to make the current object.logo as the pre-defined value of the input in my ObjectForm in the `update_object` view?

I've already tried to set `blank = True` in the logo model field (which was a bad idea). I also thought in make an alternative conditional code for `form.is_valid()` but i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Update your forms.py like so:

```py
class ObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = '__all__'
```

...and views.py:

```py
def update_object(request, value):
    object = get_object_or_404(Object, pk=value)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ObjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=object)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myApp:detail_object', args=(value, )))
    else:
        form = ObjectForm(instance=object)
    context = {'object': object, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'myApp/update_object.html', context)
```

It can be done like this (more clean)

- In case share your template code